# How to do proper error handling with Gulp?

Tags: gulp

With Gulp it is pretty easy to orchestrate a build consisting of many little steps processed through a pipe.

One of the tasks in my current Gulp setup looks like this:

```
gulp.task("release-assets", ["angular-templates", "less-compile"], function() {
    var assets = useref.assets();
    var jsFilter = filter("**/*.js");
    var moonwalkFilter = filter("**/" + MOONWALK_JS);
    var cssFilter = filter("**/*.css");

    return gulp.src("./Content/**/*.cshtml")
        .pipe(assets)               // Concatenate with gulp-useref
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())         // Process javascript sources to add dependency injection annotations
        .pipe(uglify())             // Minify javascript sources
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe(less())               // Generate CSS from LESS
        .pipe(cmq({ log: true }))   // Combine matching media queries into one media query definition
        .pipe(minifyCSS())          // Minify CSS sources
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
        .pipe(moonwalkFilter)       // Filter the moonwalk.js source file, which is generated above by useref
        .pipe(addsrc("Temp/" + TEMPLATES_JS))// Add the templates.js to the stream, which is generated by a seperate task
        .pipe(order(["**/" + MOONWALK_JS, "*.js"]))// Order stream, so that templates.js is appended to moonwalk.js (needed, since templates depend on the angular module)
        .pipe(concat(MOONWALK_JS))// Concat the existing moonwalk.js and the templates.js into moonwalk.js
        .pipe(moonwalkFilter.restore())
        .pipe(rev())                // Rename the concatenated files
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())             // Replace the original references in the cshtml with the concatenated and processed resources by usemin
        .pipe(revReplace({replaceInExtensions:[".cshtml"]}))         // Replace the usemin generated resources with the reved resources
        .pipe(gulp.dest("Dist/"));
});
```

How do I do proper error handling in this task?
What I want:
- The build should fail if one of the dependencies of the task fails
- The build should fail and report an meaningful error fi one of the steps in this task produces an error.

As far as I gather, I have to care about error handling in the pipe/streams myself ... how do I do that?
Do I really have to include a `on("error", errorHandler)` after every step in the pipe?
Is there any documentation about error handling in Gulp?

Answer (score 6):

> Do I really have to include a on("error", errorHandler) after every step in the pipe?

Yes, unless you make use of a module that can merge all of these error events into a single one. Have a look at [stream-combiner](https://github.com/substack/stream-combiner2), which can do this. There's an example recipe in the gulp docs that references using this module to listen for errors in the pipe:

```
var combiner = require('stream-combiner2');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('test', function() {
  var combined = combiner.obj([
    gulp.src('bootstrap/js/*.js'),
    uglify(),
    gulp.dest('public/bootstrap')
  ]);

  // any errors in the above streams will get caught
  // by this listener, instead of being thrown:
  combined.on('error', console.error.bind(console));

  return combined;
});
```

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/combining-streams-to-handle-errors.md

So, wrap your stream with combiner as in the example and you'll have a single error handler.

Comment: Why do I have to bind console to error? 
Doesn't `combined.on('error', console.error);` do the same thing?